# Black screen when trying to install ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, asus

I have Intel® Core™ i7-6700K Processor (64bit) on Asus maximus hero VIII motherboard. I want to install ubuntu 16.04 64-bit on this hardware.

However, when I click on `install ubuntu` on the UEFI GRUB menu, the screen just goes black completely. Anyone knows why? I've pretty much tried all solutions I've found on the Internet.

Things I've tried:

- nomodeset, acpi=off, nolapic
- Making sure checksum of iso image is correct (checksum)
- Tried both USB and DVD
- Tried both HDMI and display ports (the motherboard doesn't have VGA)
- Disabling Secure Boot, Fast Boot, enabling/disabling CSM

UPDATED: [This is what I see when trying to install using legacy EFI mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwQn1.jpg)

UPDATED: in legacy EFI mode, If I set acpi=off or nomodeset I got different kernel errors, but when I set noapic, I got a black screen with a blinking cursor.

UPDATED: After updating BIOS, for UEFI mode, `install ubuntu` option no longer gives me black screen but it immediately restarts the PC. `try ubuntu` option still gives me black screen

Comment: When downloading the iso did you use checksum? The problem could be with the iso you used!

Comment: Hi Muaad, thanks for your comment. I did check the checksum

Comment: Try going into the live version and install it from there.

Comment: You mean `try Ubuntu without installing`? I tried that and also black screen. I tried installing using legacy mode and got kernel panic I updated the question with the logs

Comment: What kind of graphics card do you have?

Comment: I have NVIDIA TITAN X but it's not plugged in.

Comment: How is it not plugged in? Anyway NVIDIA is known for driver issues on Linux.

Comment: I'm currently plugging the display ports cable directly to the motherboard first

Comment: Try connection the VGA and try again.

Comment: Unfortunately, this motherboard and this Graphics card don't have VGA port